# How to change mHandler.postDelayed method's timer from different activity?

Tags: handler, runnable

I am new to android...
I have created an android application which refreshes after every 5 seconds.
For refreshing I have used Handler and Runnable..
In this app, RefreshActivity is used to implement handler and runnable...
UpdateActivity is used to set new timer but since I have defined Runnable and Handler in RefreshActivity , so I cant access them from UpdateActivity.
So please help me to solve this issue.
.
.
I have attached code of above two activities..

on RefreshActivity

```
private final Runnable m_Runnable = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()

    {
        if(delayedAgain)
        {
            delayedAgain = false;
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, newDelayedTimeFromNow);  
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(RefreshActivity.this,"in runnable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        number++;
        RefreshActivity.this.mHandler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, newDelayedTimeFromNow);            
    }

};
```

on UpdateActivity

```
Button set=(Button)findViewById(R.id.set); 

    set.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            t = timer.getText().toString() ;
            time= Integer.parseInt(t);

            System.out.println("New Time in milisec : "+ newDelayedTimeFromNow);

RefreshActivity.this.delayedAgain = true;
RefreshActivity.this.newDelayedTimeFromNow = time * 1000;



        }
    });
```

t is the editText in which I insert new timer values in seconds...
.